# How do I use the same Samsung account on all of my Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, accounts

I am wondering if it is possible to use the *exact same* Samsung Account on multiple Samsung devices?

I have a specific Samsung account (Gmail account) I want to use on my Samsung devices (I have 4 Samsung devices), but when I try to add the Gmail address I want to use for my Samsung account on my Samsung Galaxy A52 5G smartphone, it gives me an error that states the Samsung account is being used on another device.

I do know I am using the same Samsung account on my Samsung Galaxy Tablet and my Samsung Galaxy A52 5G right now, but it is *not* the account I wanted to use.

Why would it give me this error message? Can anyone please help me with this? Is there perhaps an app or something out there that can help me with this?

Please explain in a detailed manner so I can understand it, I am not a professional user of mobile devices. The easiest route is perfectly fine with me.

Comment: Could you quote the exact error message?